# Morphing Character into another

Tags: shape-keys

I'm still getting to know blender a bit and I was curious if there was a way to achieve a morphing/shapeshift effect using separate character models - specifically from MB-Lab. I know you can change the model with shapekeys, but that requires manually editing the vertexes into the target shape. Is there perhaps another method? Or at the very least, any tricks to make manual vertex editing a bit less tedious? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can apply some modifiers as a shapekey. May be you can earn the new shape easier with a shrinkwrap modifier.